# Accessing $_SESSION from within a class

Tags: php, oop

Any reason why I wouldn't be able to access $_SESSION vars I created in "Class A" within a different class, say "Class B"? If I var_dump outside of the Class B, its fine, but within Class B, its report undefined.

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: please show the part of your code where class b is called.

Comment: Ive tried to access them in the contruct and functions.

Comment: Unless `session_start()` was not previously called on the script, `$_SESSION` is superglobal and available everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have started a session (session_start()) somewhere in your code you should be able to access the $_SESSION superglobal from anywhere within the same request.

If you're loading class B in a separate request, make sure you've started the session. If this still doesn't work, look at your php configuration.

Comment: Aaah that was exactly the problem thank you!! Had to load session_start again as it was in a seperate request.